# How to test IE intranet zone

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, windows-domain

how I can I tell whethear IE treats the given URL as intranet zone or other zone?

I have trouble with Kerberos negotiate auth and I need to know if the problem is with zoning, or zone setting.

I'm in corporate domain so I dont even have access to the configuration options in IE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the page open, bring up IE's menu bar and hit File -> Properties.  It will tell you what zone the current page is in on that dialog.

[image]

Comment: It laso visible in the status bar - right side

Comment: If you are using IE 8 or lower.  Microsoft decided to remove that information as of IE 9 and later for some strange reason.